# Mime-mapping in grails 3 application

Tags: amazon-web-services, grails, character-encoding

My Grails 3/VueJS project has page encoding problems (my first page is index.html)

After trying a lot of solutions, I found out it's ok when adding ";charset=utf-8" in the html mime-mapping, in the tomcat **conf/web.xml** :

```
<mime-mapping>
        <extension>html</extension>
        <mime-type>text/html;charset=utf-8</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

As I'm deploying on AWS, I'm wondering how this configuration can be handled by my war.

I saw this link https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#contentNegotiation to configure mime-mapping in grails application but this is not working and I don't know if this the right way to do it.

Comment: As a kludge, maybe you could append `;charset=utf-8` to each of the mime types in the `grails.mime.types` config section?

Comment: I already tried but this doesn't work